# Flutter app: hide appBar action according to ApplicationState value

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I'm quite new to Flutter and I think I haven't understand all the logic behind the state management with Providers.
I've the following widget:

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {

   List<IconButton> navigationActions(BuildContext context) {
    return
      Consumer<ApplicationState>(builder: (context, appState, _) {
        if (appState.loginState == 'loggedIn') {
          return [IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
            tooltip: 'Logout',
            onPressed: () {
              context.read<ApplicationState>().signOut();
           },
          )];
        }
      })
    ;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('FOO'),
        actions: navigationActions(context)
      ),
      body: ListView(
        .........
      )
    )
 }
```

And I want to show/hide the AppBar action according to the flag *loginState* set inside ApplicationState

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ApplicationState(),
      builder: (context, _) => App(),
    ),
  );
}
```

```
class ApplicationState extends ChangeNotifier {
  ApplicationState() {
    init();
  }

  String _loginState = 'loggedOut';
  String get loginState => _loginState;
}
```

I'm not sure about how to implement the function *navigationActions*.
Which should be the return type? Since I'm not returning a data in the else branch I'm not sure about how to manage that type.
Maybe there are smarter solution, I don't know yet.. Someone has ever implemented a similar logic with Providers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`navigationActions` has to return `List<IconButton>`, but you are returning the result of `Consumer` which is a `Widget`. You can use other methods to get the `ApplicationState`. Here is example code which does what you want:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ApplicationState extends ChangeNotifier {
  String _loginState = 'loggedIn';
  set loginState(String state) {
    _loginState = state;
  }

  get loginState => _loginState;
  void toggleState() {
    if (loginState == 'loggedIn')
      loginState = 'loggedOut';
    else
      loginState = 'loggedIn';
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void signOut() {}
}

class ActionTest extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ApplicationState(),
      child: ActionApp(),
    );
  }
}

class ActionApp extends StatelessWidget {
  List<IconButton> navigationActions(BuildContext context) {
    final appState = Provider.of<ApplicationState>(context);
    if (appState.loginState == 'loggedIn') {
      return [
        IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.logout),
          tooltip: 'Logout',
          onPressed: () {
            appState.signOut();
          },
        )
      ];
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appState = Provider.of<ApplicationState>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('FOO'), actions: navigationActions(context)),
      body: Container(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          appState.toggleState();
        },
        child: Icon(appState.loginState == 'loggedIn'
            ? Icons.toggle_off
            : Icons.toggle_on),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```